# sending notifications to user's friend in facebook using js sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, sdk

I am trying to send notification to user's friend using js sdk on facebook canvas app
but I get this in console

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/16542203957691/notifications? 400 (OK) jquery.min.js:140
c.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:140
c.extend.post jquery.min.js:133
makePost ec2-34-41-111-91.ap-southwest-8.compute.amazonaws.com/:69
onclick
```

I am calling makePost function passing it the friend's profile Id as the argument, this is what I am trying

```
function makePost(personid){
  var accesstoken =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
  var address = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + personid + "/notifications?";
  var tempdata = {};
  tempdata['access_token'] = accesstoken;
  tempdata['href'] = "";
  tempdata['template'] = "You have earned 5 credits, Click here to redeem";
  jQuery.post(address, {json: JSON.stringify(tempdata)}, function(data){
      console.log(data);
  });
}
```

the person is not receiving the notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that its not the normal access token, here the access token will be a combination of your app id and app secret separated by "|" symbol.
also you need to send the data as an array and not as a json object.

So here is what the working code looks like.

```
function makePost(personid){
  var address = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + personid + "/notifications";
  var tempdata = {};
  tempdata['access_token'] = appId + "|" + appSecret;
  tempdata['href'] = "";
  tempdata['template'] = "You have earned 5 credits, Click here to redeem";
  jQuery.post(address, tempdata , function(data){
      console.log(data);
  });
}
```

PS: I am using Jquery Library to make the post request, So dont forget to include jquery.

Comment: I am getting this error : can anyone help plz :POST https://graph.facebook.com/100006720522431/notifications 403 (OK) jquery-1.10.1.js:8724
send jquery-1.10.1.js:8724
x.extend.ajax jquery-1.10.1.js:8154
x.(anonymous function) jquery-1.10.1.js:8300
makePost my_network.html?n=fb:689
onclick

Comment: His code is correct, You have to click to run it, because that api needs mouse event, you cannot run it automatically